# Changing MainPage of a Maui app breaks OnBackPressedDispatcher callback

Tags: c#, android, .net-core, maui

I have upgraded my Maui app to use .net8 and target Android 13.  In doing so, I am trying to eliminate the deprecated `base.OnBackPressed();` but I am running into an issue.

Old logic:

```
// MainActivity.cs
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (someCondition() == true)
    {
        HandleBackPressMyself();
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I am launching my page like this:

```
// App.xaml.cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Start();
}

private async void Start()
{
    var page = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyFirstPage>();
    Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        ((App)Application.Current).MainPage = page;
        await Task.Delay(1);
    };
}
```

That is pretty straightforward and has always worked.  Now, I am trying to use the OnBackPressedDispatcher like this:

```
// MainActivity.cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback(this, new BackPressedCallback(this));
}
```

```
// BackPressedCallback.cs
public class BackPressedCallback : OnBackPressedCallback
{
    private readonly Activity activity;

    public BackPressedCallback(Activity activity) : base(true)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public override void HandleOnBackPressed()
    {
        if (someCondition() == true)
        {
            HandleBackPressMyself();
        }
        else
        {
            var mainPage = ((App)Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current)?.MainPage;
            mainPage.SendBackButtonPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works well as long as I push new pages to the stack using `await navigationPage.PushAsync(newPage);`.

However, there are a couple of scenarios where I want to remove the MainPage and replace it with an altogether new page like so:

`((App)Application.Current).MainPage = loginPage;`

As soon as I do this, the `HandleOnBackPressed()` in the `BackPressedCallback` stops firing, and all my back navigation stops working entirely.

Can anybody provide some insight on why the back handler would stop working after I set `Application.Current.MainPage = someNewPage`?

Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

I have added a github demo of the issue here that can be downloaded and played with:

https://github.com/mikeluken/MauiSample

Comment: What's the code of `HandleBackPressMyself()` and `serviceProvider` ? And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I have updated my post above with a link to a github repo that shows this, as well as some other information I have uncovered....

Comment: Is the code uploaded correctly? After downloading the code, the app will get an error after building.

Comment: Oops sorry.  It should be working now.

Comment: Is this fixed yet?

Comment: No it isn't fixed yet. We aren't using shell so the answer so far doesn't address the problem we are facing....

Answer (score 0):

On Maui, if you want to detect the back event while pressing the Navigating Bar and Android on-screen Back Buttons, you can simply do as follows.

1.create a view mode for your page and add necessary command for it to detect the back action by `Shell.Current.Navigating`.

**ThirdPageViewModel.cs**

```
 public class ThirdPageViewModel:BackBaseViewModel
   {
       public Command OnAppearingCommand { get; set; }

       public Command OnDisappearingCommand { get; set; }

       public ThirdPageViewModel()
       {
           Title = "Test Page(Back)";
           OnAppearingCommand = new Command(() => OnAppearing());
           OnDisappearingCommand = new Command(() => OnDisappearing());
       }

       private void OnAppearing()
       {
           Shell.Current.Navigating += Current_Navigating;
       }

       private void OnDisappearing()
       {
           Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating;
       }

       private async void Current_Navigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.CanCancel)
           {
               e.Cancel();
               await GoBack();
           }
       }

       private async Task GoBack()
       {
           var result = await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(
               "Going Back?",
               "Are you sure you want to go back?",
               "Yes, Please!", "Nope!");

           if (result)
           {
               Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating;
               await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
           }
       }
   }
```

**BackBaseViewModel.cs**

```
public class BackBaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

2.Then ,set the `BindContext` for your page and the `OnAppearingCommand` and `OnDisappearingCommand` for your page.

```
public partial class TestBackPage : ContentPage
{
      public TestBackPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ThirdPageViewModel();
      }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (this.BindingContext != null)
        {
            if (((ThirdPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).OnAppearingCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                ((ThirdPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).OnAppearingCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        if (this.BindingContext != null)
        {
            if (((ThirdPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).OnDisappearingCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                ((ThirdPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).OnDisappearingCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't using Shell so this doesn't solve my question while also implementing predictive back behavior. I believe this may be a bug in Maui but am not sure yet.

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said.  And if I used the shell, it just works properly.

Comment: You can create a new issue on GitHub for this problem.